# How do I horizontally center a div that has the main content between two empty divs

Tags: html, css

I have something like this:

```css
#left,
#middle,
#right {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
}

#middle {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">foo</div>
  <div id="middle">Main content goes here</div>
  <div id="right">bar</div>
</div>
```

As long as the `left` and `right` divs have *some* content, they nicely sandwich the middle div.

But as soon as I remove the content **foo** and/or **bar** from the `left` and `right` divs, the `middle` div docks itself to the left as though the left div never existed.

How do I have those three divs stay put retaining the percentage widths I have assigned to them regardless of whether or not they have any content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them `inline-block`s instead of inline elements and erase the floats

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#left,
#middle,
#right {
  display: inline-block;
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
}

#middle {
  width: 58%;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="middle">Main content goes here</div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Here's another, simpler solution if you don't need any content at the sides:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


#middle {
  width: 60%;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="middle">Main content goes here</div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try it removing the content **foo** and **bar** please? It doesn't seem to avail at my end.

Comment: I just did - see edit: The background color disappears, but the position of the middle element remains the same

Comment: Thanks so much. I have to say, though, only because I have to choose one, I find the other person called out that I had to eliminate the `float: left` in addition to choosing `inline-block`. That did it. If I could choose more than one, I'd certainly choose yours as well. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Oh, my apologies I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- Make `#left`, `#middle` and `#right` have `display: inline-block` instead of `display: inline`
- Remove the `float: left` from each of the elements
- Shrink `#middle` slightly to accommodate for the padding (I went with `width: 58%`)

Optionally:

- Add a `height` to the elements (as `inline-block` doesn't have a height by default)
- Add a `line-height` equal to `height` so that any text has the same height
- Add `vertical-align: middle` to ensure that the text is vertically centered

```css
#left,
#middle,
#right {
  display: inline-block; /* Display the elements next to each other */
  height: 30px; /* Set the images to the same height */
  line-height: 30px; /* Set the text to have the same height */
  vertical-align: middle; /* Center the text vertically */
}

#left,
#right {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
}

#middle {
  width: 58%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle">Main content goes here</div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you. That did it. Your separately calling out the differences in a prelude made a whole lot of difference. A few more minutes before I can mark this answer.

Comment: Sorry, I could only choose one answer. Your answer was very helpful. In fact, it did the trick for me mentally.

Comment: No problems; glad to hear it helped. Also just added a bit more explanation on how to handle the text :)

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is expected with *floated* elements.

Consider declaring a minimum width if the elements in question are `:empty`.

**Example:**

```
#left:empty, #right:empty {
  min-width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

#### Retaining Floats:

```css
#left, #middle, #right {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

#left, #right {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
}

#middle {
  width: 60%;
}

/* Additional */
#left:empty, #right:empty {
  min-width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 20px; /* for the sake of demonstration */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">foo</div>
    <div id="middle">Main content goes here</div>
    <div id="right">bar</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both"><br></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle">Main content goes here</div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, the `float` property could be removed in favour of `display: inline-block` property, empty elements will still retain specified widths in the DOM structure.

#### Inline Block Method:

```css
#container {
    letter-spacing: -5px; /* rid ourselves of whitespace between elements created by inline-block elements */
}

#left, #middle, #right {
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: normal; /* reset letter spacing */
}

#left, #right {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: green;
    min-height: 20px; /* for the sake of demonstration */
}

#middle {
    width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">foo</div>
    <div id="middle">Main content goes here</div>
    <div id="right">bar</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle">Main content goes here</div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Lastly, there is also `flex-box` to consider, if you haven't already, the easiest method in which to retain your layout throughout a range of conditions including ones where nested elements are empty.

#### Flex-Box Method:

```css
#container {
    display: flex; /* and that's really all you need... */
}

#left, #middle, #right {
    display: inline-block; /* useless now, but keep it here anyway for those old people still using Internet Explorer 11 */
}

#left, #right {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: green;
}

#middle {
    width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">foo</div>
    <div id="middle">Main content goes here</div>
    <div id="right">bar</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle">Main content goes here</div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```